# Can't create android sqlite DB

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am working on an android project, while am trying to create the database it seems that I have something wrong, that is my code that supposes to create a Database with multiple tables but it doesn't create any table, kindly help me find the error here :)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "StudyLife";
public static final String Table_Subject = "Subject";
public static final String sub_col1 = "ID";
public static final String sub_col2 = "Name";
public static final String sub_col3 = "NumOfHours";
//Table Class
public static final String Table_Class ="Class";
public static final String class_Col1 = "ID";
public static final String class_col2 = "Name";
public static final String class_Col3 = "Subject_ID";
public static final String class_Col4 = "Minutes ";
public static final String Class_Col5 = "Hours";
public static final String class_Col6 = "Date";
public static final String class_Col7 = "location";
public static final String class_Col8 = "Type";
//Table Tasks  && Exams
public static final String Table_Tasks ="Tasks";
public static final String Task_col1 ="ID";
public static final String Task_col2 ="Name";
public static final String Task_col3 ="Subject_ID";
public static final String Task_col4 ="Deadline";
public static final String Task_col5 ="Type";//Bool To Exam OR Task

public DataBase(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, 1);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DataBase.Table_Subject + "("+DataBase.sub_col1+" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
            + DataBase.sub_col2 + "TEXT NOT NULL ," +
              DataBase.sub_col3+" INTEGER )");


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DataBase.Table_Tasks+"("+DataBase.Task_col1+"INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            DataBase.Task_col2+ "TEXT," +
            DataBase.Task_col3+"INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            DataBase.Task_col4+ "INTEGER," +
            DataBase.Task_col5+ "INTEGER )");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DataBase.Table_Class+ "("+DataBase.class_Col1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
             DataBase.class_col2+"TEXT," +
             DataBase.class_Col3+"INTEGER," +
             DataBase.class_Col4+"TEXT," +
             DataBase.Class_Col5+"TEXT,"+
             DataBase.class_Col6+"TEXT," +
             DataBase.class_Col7+"TEXT," +
             DataBase.class_Col8+"TEXT )");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  Subject ");
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  Class" );
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  Tasks" );
    onCreate(db);

}}
```

this is what i get out in logcat after run

> 05-16 10:55:02.407 17033-17033/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> AndroidRuntime 
>   START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
>   05-16 10:55:02.423 17033-17033/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
>   05-16 10:55:02.443 17033-17033/? D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
>   05-16 10:55:02.443 17033-17033/? D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
>   05-16 10:55:02.451 17033-17033/? D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
>   05-16 10:55:02.455 17033-17033/? D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
>   05-16 10:55:02.455 17033-17033/? D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
>   05-16 10:55:02.499 1282-1288/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.499 1282-1288/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.527 772-778/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.527 772-778/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.555 1480-1486/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.559 1480-1486/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.579 17033-17033/? D/dalvikvm: Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
>   05-16 10:55:02.595 1512-1516/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.595 1512-1516/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.623 17033-17040/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.647 1546-1550/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.659 1546-1550/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.683 818-824/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.687 818-824/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.711 788-794/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.731 788-794/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.735 885-890/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.743 885-890/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.763 695-701/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.775 695-701/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.823 1207-1213/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.823 1207-1213/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.851 16791-16797/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.851 1529-1534/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.883 1529-1534/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.883 1498-1504/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.927 1498-1504/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.931 1051-1057/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.939 1051-1057/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.955 637-643/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.979 637-643/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.979 830-837/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:02.999 830-837/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.023 17033-17033/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   05-16 10:55:03.023 17033-17033/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   05-16 10:55:03.139 17033-17033/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
>   05-16 10:55:03.187 17033-17033/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   05-16 10:55:03.191 17033-17040/? D/jdwp: Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
>   05-16 10:55:03.195 17033-17040/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
>   05-16 10:55:03.223 1282-1288/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.239 1282-1288/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.247 772-778/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.283 1480-1486/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.283 772-778/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.323 1512-1516/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.335 1480-1486/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.343 1546-1550/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.359 1512-1516/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.387 818-824/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.395 1546-1550/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.431 788-794/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.431 818-824/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.475 885-890/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.491 788-794/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.679 695-701/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.755 885-890/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.755 1207-1213/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.827 695-701/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.831 1529-1534/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.871 1207-1213/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.891 1498-1504/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.903 16791-16797/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.919 1051-1057/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.939 1529-1534/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:03.939 637-643/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:04.007 830-837/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:04.007 1498-1504/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:04.071 1051-1057/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:04.087 637-643/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>   05-16 10:55:04.107 830-837/? I/jdwp: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping

Comment: Can you post the logcat error here? Only thing I can think of just by looking at the code is to put a space between the table name and the first `(` in your `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: *Every question* which includes *"it shows an error"* or similar needs to say what the error is.

Comment: missing spaces, check the concatenated strings

Comment: @MichaelDodd the post is edited

Comment: @AnsamM.AbdEl-Rasoul Still doesn't show any useful information though. Look for a line beginning with `E/` and containing the phrase `Caused By:`

Comment: For Confirmation: Have you created the object of Database class ?? Database mydb = new Database(getApplicationContext()); (you can remove all other parameters in constructor other than Context) so that the oncreate is called. ??Make note the oncreate is called only once! Also try clear data of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess since you've not posted the logcat, but I think you need a space in between the table name and first open bracket. So for example:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DataBase.Table_Subject + " (" +
        DataBase.sub_col1 + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
        DataBase.sub_col2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
        DataBase.sub_col3 + " INTEGER )"
    );

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DataBase.Table_Tasks + " (" + 
        DataBase.Task_col1 + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        DataBase.Task_col2 + " TEXT," +
        DataBase.Task_col3 + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
        DataBase.Task_col4 + " INTEGER," +
        DataBase.Task_col5 + " INTEGER )"
    );

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DataBase.Table_Class + " (" + 
         DataBase.class_Col1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
         DataBase.class_col2 + " TEXT," +
         DataBase.class_Col3 + " INTEGER," +
         DataBase.class_Col4 + " TEXT," +
         DataBase.class_Col5 + " TEXT," +
         DataBase.class_Col6 + " TEXT," +
         DataBase.class_Col7 + " TEXT," +
         DataBase.class_Col8 + " TEXT )"
     );
```

**EDIT:** Also noted that you're not consistently adding spaces after your field names too. Please dump *all* of your `CREATE TABLE` statements to logcat, and try to neatly code your statements as above so it's easier to pick up concatenation errors.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Can you include the logcat, with the advice I posted above? (i.e. find the line containing `Caused By`)

Comment: Also for `class_Col4` - get rid of the space at the end of `"Minutes "`

Answer (score 0):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DataBase.Table_Subject + " ("+DataBase.sub_col1 +" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + DataBase.sub_col2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
          DataBase.sub_col3 + " INTEGER);");


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DataBase.Table_Tasks + " ("+DataBase.Task_col1 + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        DataBase.Task_col2 + " TEXT, " +
        DataBase.Task_col3 + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
        DataBase.Task_col4 + " INTEGER, " +
        DataBase.Task_col5 + " INTEGER);");

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DataBase.Table_Class + " ("+DataBase.class_Col1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
         DataBase.class_col2 + " TEXT, " +
         DataBase.class_Col3 + " INTEGER, " +
         DataBase.class_Col4 + " TEXT, " +
         DataBase.Class_Col5 + " TEXT, "+
         DataBase.class_Col6 + " TEXT, " +
         DataBase.class_Col7 + " TEXT, " +
         DataBase.class_Col8 + " TEXT);");
```

Hope this works. 
No ; at the end of the SQL statement and also no spaces given after column name and before data type.

As there is no logcat information, If oncreate() gets called, then this code should work. If this does not work, then please let me know if onCreate() is getting called or not by adding logs.